# Resolving dependencies in WebForms UserControls using Structuremap

Tags: dependency-injection, webforms, structuremap

I'm currently using a httpmodule to inject my page level permissions using the ObjectFactory.BuildUp() method by structuremap.

I want to do the same thing with webforms user controls. I have a base usercontrol that all my usercontrols inherit. In this I tried to do:

```
public abstract class BaseUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public BaseUserControl()
    {
        ObjectFactory.BuildUp(this);   
    }
}
```

However, my dependencies are not injected in my derived user controls.

Any ideas as to how I can do this?

Comment: That should work, how are you configuring your setter conventions?  Are you using SetAllProperties, or specifying them per control?